# Pandas df create a column that adds up the last two numbers of a different column

Tags: python, pandas

| Index | Value | Value sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | 30 |
| 3 | 20 | 50 |
| 4 | 30 | 80 |
| 5 | 20 | 100 |

Something like that, it should be a lambda function I assume but I can't figure it out.

```
df['value sum'] = df['value']
df['value sum'].iloc[1] = df['value sum'].iloc[0] + df['value sum'].iloc[1]
```

This works if I keep pasting it for the whole dataframe, but it's not automatic.

Comment: Have you tried [Series.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)?

Comment: Enke, yeah sorry, I am trying my best but rely on the table visualization, not my English!

Nick, I will try, how should I use it?

Comment: Nick, yeah that worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description and pseudo-code, it sounds like you want to use `rolling` (though this doesn't match your sample column values).  `rolling` allows you to add the previous `n` rows in current, for example:

```
d = {'Index': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5},
 'Value': {0: 10, 1: 20, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 20},
 'Value sum': {0: 10, 1: 30, 2: 50, 3: 80, 4: 100}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)  

df['RollingSum'] = df.Value.rolling(window=3, min_periods=0).sum()
```

output:

```
   Index  Value  Value sum  RollingSum
0      1     10         10        10.0
1      2     20         30        30.0
2      3     20         50        50.0
3      4     30         80        70.0
4      5     20        100        70.0
```

(if you want `Value sum`, `df.Value.cumsum()` will work as pointed out in the comments.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
value = [10, 20, 20, 30, 20]
sum = [x for x in value] # initializes array sum with same values
for x in range(1, len(value)):
    sum[x] = sum[x - 1] + value[x] # calculates each sum
d = {'value': value, 'sum': sum}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d, index = range(1, 6))
df
```